# output row names containing NA in atleast one data.frame

Tags: r, subset

I have two dataframes:

df1:

```
        c1-1       c2-45      c3-65      c4-88         c5-97
r1        NA    0.598817857 0.053798422 0.776829475      NA
r2  0.481191121 0.67205121  0.50231424  0.933501988 0.169838618
r3  0.127680486       NA    0.188186772       NA    0.410198769
r4  0.448870194 0.372560979 0.627946034 0.277422856 0.540501786
r5  0.828152448 0.962372344 0.72686092  0.881644452 0.822969723
```

df2:

```
          c1-24     c2-98     c3-77        c4-82       c5-9
r1  0.528260595 0.602697657 0.15193253  0.458712206 0.785602995
r2  0.250479754 0.999715659 0.575051699     NA      0.830962509
r3     NA           NA      0.733031402 0.189934875 0.554902551
r4  0.160801532 0.611729999 0.665725625 0.966146299 0.005503371
r5  0.483603251 0.306977032 0.377184726 0.109827232 0.63159439
```

both of them contain the same row names, but contain different column names (the string before the '-' symbol is the same for both dataframes but the string after is different).

I would like to compare the two dataframes and output rows that contain NA in atleast one of them. for example: the output in the above example would be:

r1, r2, r3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `is.na` to check for `NA` values
- Use `|` to get `TRUE` if either `df1` or `df2` has `NA`.
- `rowSums` to count `NA` values in the row
- return rownames of only those rows that have more than 0 `NA` values.

```
rownames(df1)[rowSums(is.na(df1) | is.na(df2)) > 0]
#[1] "r1" "r2" "r3"
```

Comment: perfect. thankfs for the explanation too!

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
row.names(df1)[Reduce(`|`, lapply(df1 * df2, is.na))]
```

-output

```
[1] "r1" "r2" "r3"
```